# Unable to reach Browser:Session Not Created Exception

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Below is the testcase code which doesn't seem to be executing anyways. Is there any configuration problem with firefox?

```
package testOperations;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class FunctionalTest {

    //Code for launching the required link into browser

    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest

    public void  launchUrl() {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C://MavenTest//driver/geckodriver.exe");
       driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("https://letskodeit.teachable.com/p/practice");

    }
```

On running the code only blank browser window is being open and the testcases are giving failures.

```
    @Test

    public void radioButtoncheck() {

    boolean list = driver.findElements(By.tagName("radio")).get(2).isSelected();

        if  (list!=true) {

            driver.findElement(By.id("hondaradio")).click();
        }
        else {

            driver.findElement(By.id("benzradio")).click();
        }

    }

}
```

[Output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBsU7.png)

Comment: Could you please attach the error output you get when running the test?

Comment: Testcase failure output screenshot

Comment: I am using selenium standalone 3.0.1 and geckodriver as well still its showing blank morzilla browser tabs open.

Comment: As what I can see from your screenshot, there is no error output visible (maybe configure your log4j properly, or run maven with `-e -X` to get more advanced output.

Comment: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true, firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@4facf68f, browserName=firefox,

Comment: In the comment above I have posted the error as it is displaying blank morzilla pages

Answer (score 1):

**Finally I got the answer.Do look if anyone is getting configuration failure with latest geckdriver and morzilla browser version**

Use This

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "C://MavenTest//driver/geckodriver.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

Code wrong @

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C://MavenTest//driver/geckodriver.exe");
```

Use

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C://MavenTest//driver//geckodriver.exe");
```

"//" should be placed instead of "/"

Comment: if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")) {
    
     System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C://MavenTest//driver//geckodriver.exe");
    
     driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    
   }
    else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
    
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C://MavenTest//driver//chromedriver.exe");
    
     driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
   } I have used this code in order to check.So Igot that chrome driver is working fine Is there any new dependency for geckodriver 64bit version.

Comment: To use geckodriver your firefox version must be higher than 47. please check and update to latest version